# USB: Virtual COM port specification

Tags: serial-port, usb, libusb, usbserial

In Windows it is possible to create a virtual COM port to communicate with an USB device. However I could not find any specification how this actually works under the hood, i.e. how input to this device is converted into USB commands (control commands, I suppose) and back.

I'm asking because I have a USB device which has lots of documentation how to control it via virtual COM ports but I'd like to use it on non-Windows Systems (i.e. with libusb).

If anyone can point me to a RFC or similar, I'd be really happy: reverse-engineering the commands via USB capture would take way more time...

Comment: Most USB->COM chipsets have linux drivers already. Those have source code...

Comment: I'm not sure what chipset you are referring to. It may be there's a chipset built into the device but I don't know what it may be. I can only connect it via USB yet the documentation always refers to virtual COM ports. From your comment I gather that there's no common specification for virtual USB COM ports and it is up to the manufacturer of individual devices on how that should work?

Comment: In cases like this the easiest way is (afaik) to sniff the virtual com port driver interacting with the device and reproduce this in your own software.